# How to translate "schön blöd" in English?

Tags: german-to-english

What does "schön blöd"  mean?

Is it offending, but meant as a joke? Or does it mean someone is awfully stupid?  In which situation would/could Germans use it?

Comment: I think more context is needed here.

Comment: @Gigili i read it in a chat, so someone was calling somebody to be "schön blöd". Looks to me like being "abnormaly stupid". But "schön" is confusing me. Can it only be used for persons?

Comment: @Gigili: Actually, no context is needed here. I like the question! But I'm having difficulty to explain the expression ...

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: According to [dict](http://www.dict.cc/?s=bl%C3%B6d), it has levels of being offensive. that's what I mean. how can you say it's a joke or insult without context?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: I should have listened to you - it was really kind of difficult to try to explain it :) I hope I wrote something understandable :D

Comment: @Gigili: "blöd" may be offensive. "schön blöd" is a set expression and may be used to make fun of someone, but it's not really insulting.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Not bad at all! @Gigili (maybe you find this comment): OregonGhost explained it nicely, you don't need context because it's a set phrase.

Comment: @oregon say you have a stereotype blonde beautiful ignorant girl. If you call her "schön blöd" is it insulting or making a joke, german wordplay? Is this the origin of the term, being schön and blöd?

Comment: @Hauser: I don't think that that's the origin of the term; as described in my answer, *Schönheit* is rather the quality of a good example and does not refer to a beautiful person. Calling your hypothetical *schön blöd* wouldn't be really different from calling anyone else *schön blöd*, though you *could* try a wordplay with this. Depends on context and audience if you succeed.

Comment: Of course it is insulting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Someone is *schön blöd* by doing something stupid; though the person should/could have known better, or because of being stubborn. It's always his/her own fault. For example:

- when you pay more for something than necessary because you are too lazy to walk a few meters.
- when you let a great opportunity slip.
- when you do more work than necessary.
- when you lose a lottery prize because you forgot to turn in your ticket in time.
- when you miss a train because you had to get going last-minute.

These are just a few I could come up with. *Schön blöd* is similar to *selbst schuld*, or often used together. I think the *Schönheit* (beauty) is in the expression because it is kind of entertaining for others, as a great example of what *not* to do - a great example for stupidity. The adjective is often used to express that something is great to watch - for example, after a great goal, you may say *schönes Tor*.

Because you asked when or how Germans use it, here are some examples, in the spirit of the situations I already listed:

> Du hattest sechs Richtige im Lotto, hast aber nicht rechtzeitig abgegeben? *Schön blöd.*
>
> Du hast den ganzen Tag geschuftet, um zehn Euro zu sparen? *Schön blöd.*

In both examples, *Selbst schuld* could have been used instead.

Both are typically used only informally. They are not really insulting, but may express *Spott und Häme* (mockery).

In chats, you might also encounter *sskm*, which means *Selbst schuld, kein Mitleid*.

Comment: so could you also say that an idea is schön blöd? Or does it always relate to a person or action of a person?

Comment: @Hauser: If implementing the idea will result in the implementer being *schön blöd*, I guess you could say so. It is not a *schön blöde Idee* though, you can only say *die Idee ist schön blöd*. It is mostly, however, applied to a person or the action.

Answer (score 9):

'Schön' doesn't mean beautiful here, but 'pretty'. You can say 'schön dick', 'schön krank', 'schön schmutzig' too - it just means as much as 'recht dick', 'recht krank', 'recht schmutzig' oder 'recht blöd' - or 'ziemlich'.

Isn't 'pretty' used the same way? It was pretty stupid to lose the lottery ticket! But: the pretty girl.

Comment: I think "pretty stupid" means "very stupid", which is not the same as "schön blöd". By the way, dict.cc lists "to be pretty stupid" as "einen an der Waffel haben", which is also not the same ;) As an adverb, on the other hand, it is listed as "ziemlich" and "ganz schön".

Comment: Imho, 'shön blöd' means 'very stupid', of course it does. And what's the problem with 'pretty stupid' as 'einen an der Waffel haben'? Ganz schön verworren?